# How to use Three20 TTMessageController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I am new to iOS development. For my little messenger I need a contact picker and a textarea. So the [TTMessageController of the Three20 project](https://github.com/facebook/three20) seems to be very interesting.

However I am not really sure how to implement it. For now I have three controllers, one for each view. I want to have a contact picker and textarea on the third view.

I have set up three20 successfully. But how do I use it? Can I use it through interface builder or just by code? What would be an approach in my case?

Before I get started on this I want to be sure that this is the right solution. Is it true that three20 lets me decide how to deal with the input that comes from the text fields? I want to send sms with my own gateway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the source code for the TTCatalog example app that comes with the three20 source. It has an example of calling TTMessageController and handling the fields. Basically you implement the TTMessageControllerDelegate in your class and the TTMessageController will send the fields from the message to you for processing once the send button is pressed. I'm using this class as a front end for sending SMS messages via 3rd party gateway in my app. I've combined it with a message bubble view to mimic the native SMS application and it works like a champ.

EDIT:  If you just have a skeleton of a view controller at this point you might be better off cloning MessageTestController into your app and adapting it rather than trying to reimplement bits of it in your controller. One thing the sample app doesn't do is hook the MessageController to your addressbook. For that you'll need to create a AddressbookModel and AddressBookModelDataSource like this:

AddressbookDataSource.h

```
#import <Three20/Three20.h>

@class AddressBookModel;

@interface AddressBookDataSource : TTSectionedDataSource {
    AddressBookModel* _addressBook;
}

@property(nonatomic,readonly) AddressBookModel* addressBook;

@end
```

AddressbookDataSource.m

```
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

#import "AddressBookDataSource.h"
#import "AddressBookModel.h"

@implementation AddressBookDataSource

@synthesize addressBook = _addressBook;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// NSObject

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _addressBook = [AddressBookModel new];
        self.model = _addressBook;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    RELEASE_SAFELY(_addressBook);
    RELEASE_SAFELY(self.items);

    [super dealloc];
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TTTableViewDataSource


- (void)tableViewDidLoadModel:(UITableView*)tableView {

    RELEASE_SAFELY(self.items);

    self.items = [NSMutableArray new];
    int countPeople = [((AddressBookModel *)self.model).searchResults count];

    for (int i = 0; i < countPeople; i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = [((AddressBookModel*)self.model).searchResults objectAtIndex:i];
        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        NSArray* phoneNumbers = (NSArray*)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneNumberMultiValueRef);
        RELEASE_CF_SAFELY(phoneNumberMultiValueRef);

        if ([phoneNumbers count]) {
            NSString *personName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
            for (NSString *phoneNumber in phoneNumbers) {

                TTTableItem* item = [TTTableSubtitleItem itemWithText:personName subtitle:phoneNumber];
                [_items addObject:item];
            }
            RELEASE_SAFELY(personName);
        }
        RELEASE_SAFELY(phoneNumbers);
    }
} 

- (void)search:(NSString*)text {
    [_addressBook search:text];
}

- (NSString*)titleForLoading:(BOOL)reloading {
    return @"Searching...";
}

- (NSString*)titleForNoData {
    return @"No names found";
}

@end
```

AddressBookModel.h

```
#import <Three20/Three20.h>

@interface AddressBookModel : NSObject <TTModel> {
    NSMutableArray* _delegates;
    NSArray* _searchResults;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray* searchResults;

- (void)search:(NSString*)text;

@end
```

AddressBookModel.m

```
#import "AddressBookModel.h"
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@implementation AddressBookModel

@synthesize searchResults = _searchResults;


- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _delegates = nil;
        _searchResults = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    RELEASE_SAFELY(_delegates);
    RELEASE_SAFELY(_searchResults);
    [super dealloc];
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TTModel

- (NSMutableArray*)delegates {
    if (!_delegates) {
        _delegates = TTCreateNonRetainingArray();
    }
    return _delegates;
}

- (BOOL)isLoadingMore {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)isOutdated {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)isLoaded {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isLoading {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)isEmpty {
    return !_searchResults.count;
}

- (void)load:(TTURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy more:(BOOL)more {
}

- (void)invalidate:(BOOL)erase {
}

- (void)cancel {
    [_delegates perform:@selector(modelDidCancelLoad:) withObject:self];
}


- (void)search:(NSString*)text {
    [self cancel];

    if (text.length) {
        [_delegates perform:@selector(modelDidStartLoad:) withObject:self];

        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

        CFStringRef searchText = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        self.searchResults = (NSArray*) ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, searchText);

        RELEASE_CF_SAFELY(searchText);

        [_delegates perform:@selector(modelDidFinishLoad:) withObject:self];

        RELEASE_CF_SAFELY(addressBook);
    } else {
        self.searchResults = nil;
    }
    [_delegates perform:@selector(modelDidChange:) withObject:self];
} 

@end
```

The addressbook stuff was seriously the hardest part of the whole exercise. The rest is really easy.

Comment: I found the MessageTestController but I am not sure what code I need for my app. I have a SecondViewController (UIViewController) that is empty and I want to add the compose sms feature to that view. Can you provide a bit more help on this please

Comment: Thanks, I gonna try that. However I have a MainViewController with a navigation bar and a button "compose". I want the composer to pop up on click. The TTMessageViewController is strange for me because UI and background logic is kind of mixed up...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do in my app. Just create a method like this for your compose button.

`- (void)add { 
 TTMessageController* messageComposer = [[TTMessageController alloc] initWithRecipients:nil messageText:@""];
 
 messageComposer.delegate = self;
 
 [self presentModalViewController:messageComposer.navigationController animated:YES];
 RELEASE_SAFELY(messageComposer);
}`

Comment: I get a warning on perform:withObject, it xcode4 says this method is not found. Do you get this warning too? Xcode4 says I have  to use performSelector:withObject but my app crashes...any idea?