# How to use addRecipient method from Three20?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, three20

I use the [**TTMessageController**](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php) from [**Three20**](http://www.viz.co.kr/320api/_message_test_controller_8m_source.html) to display a view that is similar to the iPhone SMS application containing a recipient picker.

Currently I am able to autosearch contacts and to browse them by clicking on the **+** button:

[image]

However I have a problem to apply the selected contact to the recipient field. [TTMessageController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php) implements the [**addRecipient**](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php#af1a2fb598f715126dae56b41d57cdd4a) method but I am not sure how to use it.

In my controller class that extends TTMessageController I have following method which is triggered when a contact is selected, so addRecipient has to go here somewhere:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: 
                (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
                shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
    //dismiss the contact selector
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    return NO;
}
```

Any idea how to add the recipient in that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a single item from your datasource to the recipient field. So if your datasource has an array of strings (names) you call addRecipient: with a string. The index is where you want to insert the recipient in the field.

Post your datasource implementation and I will completely your code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eS6EgShL this ismy TTMessageController implementation. Search in the code for @test, test is added to the picker field so far, but I want the selected person to be added. I only want only ONE recipient to be added, so when the user clicks on add, the old recipient should be deleted

Comment: AddressBookDataSource is the relevant class. I think you will need to override TTMessageController's addRecipient and call removeAllCells on  the TTPickerTextField to clear it.

Comment: AddressBookDataSource implemetation is from the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374684/how-to-use-three20-ttmessagecontroller

Comment: Override the addRecipient if you want only 1 recipient.

Comment: I managed that using NSString *firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) ;
NSString *surname = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty) ; thank you