# Why is perform:withObject method not found?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to fix warnings in my application code. I have an `AddressBookModel.h` which implements the **TTModel** protocol.

You find both interface and implementation of the AdressBookModel in the answer of this question. This is exactly how I implemented it [How to use Three20 TTMessageController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374684/how-to-use-three20-ttmessagecontroller)

However for

```
[_delegates perform:@selector(modelDidStartLoad:) withObject:self];
```

and some other similar selectors I get warnings like

```
Method -perform:withObject not found (return type defaults to id)
```

Since _delegates is an array

```
- (NSMutableArray*)delegates {
    if (!_delegates) {
        _delegates = TTCreateNonRetainingArray();
    }
    return _delegates;
}
```

some suggested to use `makeObjectsPerformSelector` but this gives me an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` exception.

Here is the TTModel source code: http://api.three20.info/protocol_t_t_model-p.php

Why is **perform:withObject** missing? Is `performSelector:withObject` an alternative (my app crashes using it)?

Comment: What do you mean? `-performSelector:…` can accept any selector.

Comment: I mean when I let xcode complete the code, then it shows just the modelDIdStartLoad and modelDIdCancle load. So can I use modelDidCHange and modelDidFinishLoad?

Comment: What's the type of `_delegates`? Why not use `[_delegates modelDidChange:self]` directly? Also, "cancel", not "cancle".

Comment: Xcode4 is not necessarily perfect.  Have you considered the idea that the code sense simply isn't working properly?  i.e. try typing out your selector name and seeing if it works.

Comment: I updated my question with more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perform:withObject: method that produces this warning is defined in NSArray(TTCategory) category in NSArrayAdditions.h file in Three20 framework. You need to ensure that this header is imported/referenced properly by compiler, i.e. you need to look at importing this specific header or check your Three20 integration configuration.

You do not need to change this method to makeObjectsPerformSelector: since this is just an import problem (your code runs fine but just produces compile warnings).

Answer (score 5):

`_delegates` is an array of delegate***s***. It is not a true delegate, as signified from the name which is in plural form. An array does not respond to the `-modelDidFinishLoad:` method — its elements do.

You need to take each element out of the array and call the method of them, e.g.

```
for (id<TTModelDelegate> delegate in _delegates)
   [delegate modelDidFinishLoad:self];
```

or even easier, using [NSArray's `-makeObjectsPerformSelector:…`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:):

```
[_delegates makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(modelDidFinishLoad:)
                            withObject:self];
```

Comment: @Art: The class is OK. So the problem would be you added a TTPickerTextField to `.delegates`.

Comment: actually this is from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374684/how-to-use-three20-ttmessagecontroller, it works but gives me a lot of warnings, that the method "perform" is unknown. However the solutions here make the app crash

Comment: I just provide AdressBookDataSource to my TTMessageController, it handles writing the contact to the TTPickerTextField. strange, I am not sure how to solve that...

Answer (score 1):

Reading between the lines, it looks like you want the objects that are *in* your `_delegates` array to all perform a particular selector. You need to call [`-makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) like this:

```
[_delegates makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(modelDidCancelLoad:) withObject: self];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mistyping `modelDidCancleLoad:` should be `modelDidCancelLoad:`

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'-[__NSCFArray modelDidCancleLoad:]: unrecognized selector
 sent to instance 0x24f480'
```

Make sure your _delegates is what you are expecting it to be. It seems to be an NSArray.